# Make Mac OS X games with a windows computer. c#, Visual studio

Tags: c#, macos

Using a windows computer, is it possible to make a game for mac? With visual studio you can use Xamarin to make ios games, so is a there a way to do the same for mac without having to use a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Using purely visual studio... I don't know!

I know that it is possible to make cross platform games using an engine like unity:

https://unity3d.com/unity/features/multiplatform

Which uses C#, and integrates with visual studio.

There are probably other ways too!

For example, I think there is a way to make web apps with C# - which might be integrated with visual studio... but I haven't played around with it, or know what it's capabilities are.
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-5-Create-Web-b8a44cce

Web apps should be cross compatible via browsers, I think... again, haven't really played around with it.

Comment: thanks, I'll check web apps then.